# Ajax working on Localhost but not on Live Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm working on a website on which users can comment something below the `posts`, running on Python & Django.

As soon as a user comments something, then I'm updating comments without refreshing the web-page. Here's the code,

In `views.py`

```
postType1 = sorted(Posts.objects.filter( . . . ), key=lambda x: random.random())

postType2= Posts.objects.filter( . . . )
```

In template,

```
//  BLOCK - 1
{% for post in postType1 %}

<p>{{ post }}</p>

  <div class="comm_update" action="{% url 'comment:create' post.id %}">

    <form class="comm_form" action="{% url 'comment:create' post.id %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <textarea id="id_comment"></textarea><br /><br />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

  </div>

{% endfor %}

<hr />

// BLOCK - 2
{% for post in postType2 %}

<p>{{ post }}</p>

  <div class="comm_update" action="{% url 'comment:create' post.id %}">

    <form class="comm_form" action="{% url 'comment:create' post.id %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <textarea name="comment_text" id="id_comment"></textarea><br />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

  </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Auto updating comments without refreshing webpage,

```
$(document).on("submit", ".comm_form", function(t) {
t.preventDefault();
var o = $(this),
    e = $.post(o.attr("action"), o.serialize()),
    n = o.attr("action");
e.done(function(t) {
    var e = $(t).find(".comm_update[action='" + n + "']");
    o.closest(".comm_update").html(e), o[0].reset()
})
});
```

On `localhost` everything is working fine.

*But on live server the first block `BLOCK - 1` is not updating the comments, instead when user presses `submit` entire comment section disappears.

How can we fix this issue?

Thank You!

Comment: Check the JS console for errors.

Comment: @peeebeee Sir, it's not showing any errors.